# A definition of zeros of a complex function.

Tags: complex-analysis

I’m studying complex variables with a book written by Churchill.

In the textbook, he defines a point as a zero of a function only when it is zero and analytic at the point. But I don’t understand why we need analyticity when we talk about zeros.

I suspect that people didn’t want a point to be zeros and poles of a function at the same time. If we didn’t require a function to be analytic, then, for example, we just can bring a function which has a pole at a point z and redefine the function at a point z by zero. Then z is a zero and a pole at the same time. 
(* A pole of a function is an isolated singular point at which the principal part of its Laurent Series has at least one non-zero term and finitely many non-zero terms)

But I don’t know why they shouldn’t appear at the same point. Is there any reason for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you specify the edition and page number for this definition, and perhaps quote it verbatim? I am looking at a second edition of Churchill (from 1960), and on page 52 it simply says "A value of $z$ for which $f(z)=0$ is called a *zero* of the function $f$."

Comment: @Barry Cipra, 8th edition and page 249 of section 75 zeros of analytic function.

Comment: Suppose that f is analytic at z. If f(z) = 0 and if there is a positive integer m such that m-th derivative at z is not zero and each derivative of lower order vanishes at z , then f is said to have a zero of order m at z.

Comment: Oh. It says about a zero of order... I’m sorry! But I believe I never seen a definition of zero in other pages.

Comment: The excerpt I cited was in a section on "Further Properties of Trigonometric Functions." It was immediately followed by the assertion that "*the real zeros of sin z and cos z are their only zeros.*" In the second edition, "Zeros of Analytic Functions" is section 65, on page 149. The book has clearly undergone some expansion!

Comment: Oh my book doesn’t have a section called ’Further properties of Trigonometric functions’! Yes! It’s undergone some expansions! Then my question is changed... Can I say that A pole of a function can be a zero, but not a zero of order m?

Comment: BTW, you can delete a question if it has not received any (upvoted) answers.

Comment: Thank you! I will delete it soon!

Comment: Poles and zeros are quite different, and a pole is *not* a zero. What *is* the case is that $f$ has a pole of order $m$ at a point $z$ if and only if its reciprocal, $1/f$, is analytic at $z$ and has a zero of order $m$ there. Being analytic is quite important here.

Comment: Is this incorrect that a function f such that $f(1)=0 and f(z)=1/(z-1)$ has a pole and a zero at $z=1$?

Comment: Ah, I see what you're asking now. That's actually an interesting question! To answer it requires looking at exactly how Churchill defines things.

Comment: Sorry.. My English isn’t good enough to clarify my question. I will leave my post undeleted! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function

$$f(z)=\begin{cases}{1\over z}&\text{if }z\not=0\\0&\text{if }z=0\end{cases}$$

(similar to what the OP asks about in comments) meets the definitions in (my edition, at least, of) Churchill for having both a *zero* at $z=0$ and a (simple) *pole* at $z=0$.  In particular, the definition of a zero does not mention anything about continuity (much less analyticity), while the definitions of (isolated) singularities and poles do not mention whether the function is or is not assigned a value at the singular point, only that it's analytic in a neighborhood *around* the point.

So technically yes, a function *can* have both a zero and a pole at the same point.  This is kind of a trick answer to a trick question: the assignment of the value $0$ to $f(0)$ is quite arbitrary, since no value makes the continuous at $z=0$. But kudos to the OP for wondering whether Churchill's definitions allow it.

Answer (score 2):

The condition of being analytic for $f(z)$ at its zero $z=a$(say) is inherent which can be verified by just looking at the definition of the order of a zero of $f(z)$ i.e.

> "A function $f(z)$ has a zero of order $m$ at $z=a$ if $f(z)=(z-a)^mg(z)$, where $g(a)\ne 0$ and $g(z)$ is analytic at $z=a$ ".

Analyticity of $g$ at $z=a$ necessitates  analyticity of $f$ at $z=a$. In contrast, while displaying the functional value of a real function $f(x)$ at a point $x=a$ of its domain, it is not necessary that $f$ is *continuous/differentiable* there. For example, $f(x)=0$, if $x\le 0$ and $f(x)=1$ elsewhere on $\mathbb R$, you can see $f(0)=0$. Further, $x=a$ is not necessarily the limit point of the domain of $f$ for defining $f(a)$ e.g. if $A=${$0$}$\cup (1,\infty)$ and a function  $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined as $f(x)=0$ if $x=0$ and $f(x)=x$ elsewhere is a continuous function on its domain. However, the domain of a complex continuous function can't have isolated points inside it.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. One more question! If we define a function f by &f(1)=0  and f(z)=1/(z-1)& Then z=1 is clearly a pole of order 1. Is it a zero?

Comment: Defining $f$ in such a way leads to a contradiction at $z=1$ actually. A point $z=a$ is either a singularity of $f$ or a point in domain of analyticity of $f$.